# How to get rid of a list in Python when the element value of a list is a list

Tags: python, arrays, list

I want change Python list

before : `[('1','2',['3','4']),('5','6',['7','8'])]`

after : `[('1','2','3','4'),('5','6','7','8')]`

how?
please help me.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: take a look at [itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
a = [('aa', 'bb', ['cc', 'dd']), ('ee', 'ff', ['gg', 'ff'])]

def flatten(tup):
    lst = []
    for x in tup:
        if isinstance(x, list):
            lst += x
        else:
            lst.append(x)
    return tuple(lst)

output = [flatten(t) for t in a]
print(output) # [('aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd'), ('ee', 'ff', 'gg', 'ff')]
```

As you pointed out, applying [How to make a flat list out of a list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists) would result in `[('a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'cc', 'dd'), ('e', 'e', 'f', 'f', 'gg', 'ff')]` instead.

Comment: Thank you !   but if  a = [('aa','bb',['cc','dd']),('ee','ff',['gg','ff'])]  ?

Comment: @최명수 I've edited the answer accordingly.